# Removing space between the number and the caption

Tags: spacing, floats, captions

I looked through previously discussed problems but I couldn't resolve my problem.

I try to remove the space after Figure S and the numbering in the caption i.e.,

Figure S 1. text text text text text.

I want my output to be something like:
Figure S1. text text text text text.

Here is my code:

````
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},labelformat={default},name={Figure S}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=150mm]{Fig-1.eps}
\centering
\caption{text text text text text.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document} ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own label format to include the **S** prefix in the following way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption,graphicx}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{Sfignum}{#1~S#2}
\captionsetup[figure]{
  labelfont=bf,
  labelformat=Sfignum,
  labelsep=period,
  name=Figure
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{text text text text text.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

However, references to these figures will still show up as just a number. If you want references to also include the prefix, it would be better to issue

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
```

in the document preamble.

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly.